# How can I scroll to bottom of ListView in Windows Phone 8.1 RT App?

Tags: c#, listview, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

1. I have tried ScrollIntoView() but that doesn't work because the item may or may not be in viewport.
2. I tried WinRTXAMLToolkit (VisualTreeHelper class):

   var scrollViewer = listView.GetFirstDescendantOfType();
   scrollViewer.ChangeView(null, scrollViewer.ScrollableHeight, null);

It doesn't scroll to bottom every time, and when it does not, it scrolls to slightly above (from bottom).

Answer (score 0):

```
ListView.ScrollIntoView(ListView.Items[ListView.Items.Count - 1] as YourModel, ScrollIntoViewAlignment.Leading);
```

This will work only if you have no images or any other element that will be showed after showing in `Viewport`.